# ASP MVC3 how to add system current date?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have form like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Course</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CId)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cteator)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cteator)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cteator)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

I want to insert system current date and time in the field of Date field. How can i do this. Model and cotroller are already create by scaffolding.

Answer (score 2):

Insert this before you call the editor (assuming your property is a `DateTime`)

```
@{ Model.date = DateTime.Now; }
```

If your property is a string, call `DateTime.Now.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the default value in the corresponding controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View(new SomeModel { date = DateTime.Now });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as mention below

```
@{ Model.date = DateTime.Now.ToString(); }
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Course</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CId)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cteator)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cteator)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cteator)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments

Source Error:
....................
Line 11: 
Line 12: @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
Line 13:     @{Model.date = DateTime.Now; }
Line 14:     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
Line 15:     <fieldset>